# Can't Flash ESP8266 latest firmware, says "Fast Flashing error" and "Invalid head of packet(' ')

Tags: esp8266, firmware

I can't figure out how to flash the firmware found on http://www.electrodragon.com/w/ESP8266_AT-Command_firmware. I am using `ESP8266 Download tool v3.4.4`. When I am adding a firmware in download path it goes on till a fixed percentage (77 or 99..mostly) and gives the error `Invalid head of packet, FAST FLASHING ERROR`. One more thing is that the tutorials I am using to do this have many download path entries filled in the download tool while mine are just blank. It says upload the combined file to `0x0000`. I tried uploading `V1.54...` file's content (both files) but still got the similar error(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiQ5K.png). :P

So anyone could just guide me through this as I am a complete newb into this. Please mention any other information needed in comments.

**PS**

1. I am pretty sure the power supply is adequate as I have been using esp8266 with the old firmware smoothly. I have also connected a 200uF capacitor b/w gnd and vcc(3.3v from FTDI).
2. I have double checked the connections.(Yes, GPIO0 is grounded).
3. I flashed an earlier version successfully `ai-thinker-v1.1.1.bin` but when I connected it to arduino IDE serial monitor it started giving unending gibberish text :P.